# Node JS/Express Routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I need a little guidance with routing in my Node/Express app.  Initially, I create a new business from the Business model (works fine).  After creating the business, I want a separate route which adds the current FX rates offered by that business (these fields will then be updated daily).  My business model looks like this (simplified for purpose of example):

```
let businessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   category: String,
   longDescription: String,
   images: [ {url: String, public_id: String} ],

   usdHkd: { type: String, default: "" },
   hkdUsd: { type: String, default: "" },
   rateCreatedAt: {
      type:Date,
      default:Date.now
   },
});
```

When the business is first created, only the name, category, longDesc and images are populated, with default values for the FX rate fields.  That works fine using these routes:

```
/* GET business new /business/new */
router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, asyncErrorHandler(businessNew));

/* POST business create /business */
router.post('/', isLoggedIn, upload.fields([{ name: 'images', maxCount: 10 }]), asyncErrorHandler(businessCreate));
```

I then set up separate routes/controllers like this for subsequently adding the FX rates, but I don't think these are correctly defined:

```
/* GET business index /business */
router.get('/:id/remittance/new', asyncErrorHandler(remittanceNew));

/* GET business index /business */
router.put('/:id/remittance', asyncErrorHandler(remittanceCreate));

    //Remittances New
    async remittanceNew (req, res, next) {
        let business = await Business.findById(req.params.id);
        res.render('remittanceViews/newRemittance', { business }); 
    },

    //Business Update
    async remittanceCreate (req, res, next) {

        let business = await Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.business);
        console.log(business);

        //update the post with any new properties
        business.usdHkd = req.body.business.usdHkd;
        business.hkdUsd = req.body.business.hkdUsd;
        business.rateCreatedAt = req.body.business.rateCreatedAt;

        //save the updated post in the db
        business.save();
        //redirect to show page
        res.redirect(`/business/${business.id}`);
    },
```

The error message I get when I try to update is:

```
Cannot read property 'usdHkd' of undefined
```

Can anyone please advise where I'm going wrong here?  Thanks

Comment: `req.body.business.usdHkd` -- what body parser are you using? You should note that Express by defaut does not parse the POST body, you need to use 3rd party middlewares (one is even written by Express developers) to parse POST body. Also, not all bodyparsers pass data via `req.body`. I know at least one use `req.fields` instead.

Comment: @slebetman I am using body-parser 1.18.3.  I am using req.body throughout my app without issue so im unsure why it is not recognised in this route; in fact, even if I give usdHkd a value from the backend and then try to update with a new value,  I'm still getting the same Cannot read property 'usdHkd' of undefined error.  so im not really clear exactly what is undefined, given that business.usdHkd does have a value already.  Thanks

Comment: OK. Knowing that body-parser cannot parse JSON it means you are passing request parameters via ether x-www-urlencoded or form data. Either way, regular request parameters are simple key/value pairs. That means that `req.body.business.usdHkd` does not make sense. It should either be `req.body.usdHkd` or something like it. If you **are** passing JSON then you need a different body parser for that url

Comment: My main business update route looks like this:
```
        let business = await Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.business);
        business.name = req.body.business.name;
        business.category = req.body.business.category;
        business.longDescription = req.body.business.longDescription;
```
This is working fine, so I'm not clear why I should not be following req.body.business.xxx in this additional route for the FX rates?

Comment: How are you passing `req.body.business.name`? Browsers generally cannot do this unless you do it manually by passing the data as JSON. Do you have other middleware somewhere in your code that reformats `req.body.businessName` into `req.body.business.name`? Are you passing the data via JSON? Can you show client-side code or Postman/curl screenshot/command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that `usdHkd`'s parent variable in *undefined*. Most probably, this error is coming from `business.usdHkd` in `business.usdHkd = req.body.business.usdHkd;` (you can confirm it by adding more `console.log()` lines around this line and checking the outputs).

If `business.usdHkd = req.body.business.usdHkd;` is giving error, that means, `business` is *undefined*. However, you don't need this line as `business` is already updated by `findByIdAndUpdate`.

READ: [Model.findByIdAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) and [Promises in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

```
//Business Update
async remittanceCreate (req, res, next) {

    let business = await Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.business);
    console.log(business);

    // Below code is not required since findByIdAndUpdate() will update your model
    /*
    //update the post with any new properties
    business.usdHkd = req.body.business.usdHkd;
    business.hkdUsd = req.body.business.hkdUsd;
    business.rateCreatedAt = req.body.business.rateCreatedAt;

    //save the updated post in the db
    business.save();
    */

    //redirect to show page
    res.redirect(`/business/${business.id}`);
},
```

#### UPDATE

You told that `business` is defined, but it's not getting updated. The reason is `findOneAndUpdate()` requires `new` option to be set as `true` else `findOneAndUpdate()` returns the old object (before updating it -- in a sense). So, please change the first line of `remittanceCreate()` to:

```js
let business = await Business.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.business, {new: true});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashutosh for your response. Business is definitely defined as it returns the full object in console.log.  I have tried removing the code as you suggest above, and while I don't get the error message once removed, the FX fields are also not getting updated in the database.  Any thoughts on why that might be?  Thanks!

Comment: @Martin Please check the update above. I think it should solve the issue. If not, please print `req.body.business` to ensure it has the right data, and tell me too. Thanks!

Comment: @AshutoshKS The part you commented out is the very reason for the function. Commenting it out makes the function useless. He's doing this: `let business = getFromDatabase(); business.usdHkd = newValue; business.save()`. The commented out part is **necessary**, not unimportant

Comment: AshutoshKS I have tried adding {new: true} but it is still not saving those fields to the DB. @slebetman I would have also assumed I would need that block of code, though when I add it back is it continuing to give me the Cannot read property 'usdHkd' of undefined error. Any ideas then what would be causing that?  usdHkd IS undefined at that stage because the field doesn't exist yet, hence I am trying to add it

Comment: @Martin see my comment to your question

Comment: @Martin Since `console.log(business);` is working, `req.body.business` is probably *undefined*. So, could you print `req.body` and add its output here? It will help us to understand the actual issue.

Comment: @slebetman Martin is using `findByIdAndUpdate()`, which updates the model as well, so we don't need to manually update it again. That's why, I suggested him so. Please help me understand if I should do it differently.

Comment: Hi @AshutoshKS, req.body is returning {} so it does appear to be undefined.  Though I've studied it versus my other existing routes (which are working) and I can't see why it should be undefined in this case, any ideas?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is my client side:
```
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='usd-hkd' class='standard-label'>USD vs. HKD:</label>
                    <input id='usd-hkd' class='standard-input' type='text' name='business[usdHkd]' autocomplete='off'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='usd-php' class='standard-label'>HKD vs. USD:</label>
                    <input id='usd-php' class='standard-input' type='text' name='business[usdPhp]' autocomplete='off'>
                </div>
```

Comment: @Martin Interesting. The arguments use a custom naming protocol. If parsed correctly by body-parser the variable should be `req.body["business[usdHkd]"]`, not `req.body.business.usdHkd`. Someone obviously created this system before you continued developing the code (id does not make sense otherwise how you created this system and then not know how it works - unless you just had amnesia). In my opinion your best bet is to find that someone and ask him how this all is supposed to work.

Comment: @Martin I am asking again (unless you really don't know) - how are you submitting the form? Is it via form action or ajax or something else?

Comment: @slebetman it is via form action yes.  The structure was originally taken from an online course I was following (I am a fairly inexperienced programmer) so I'm surprised you say it is a custom structure as it has been used throughout my app without issue; I am working with multiple models (business, event, blog etc.) all of which follow the same format (e.g. req.body.event.name etc.) without issue, but it is only this one that is causing me issue.  However, I am inexperienced as I say, so I am open to suggestions of how this can be changed. Thanks

Comment: @Martin If `req.body` is empty, could you share the body-parser (middleware) logic? Also, could you try submitting the form some other way (maybe using curl directly)? Also, please compare this model/route logic with some other working logic in your app (and share their code here), and try to look for differences -- even small ones matter.

Comment: Hi @Martin, please check my comment above and provide your inputs. :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses, this is now resolved.  @AshutoshKS your first answer was indeed correct, there is no need for that additional code that you commented out.  The issue was actually caused by some erroneous code in my form tag, where I had copied over from another form with 'enctype='multipart/form-data'' still included, which is not relevant here and was causing req.body to return an empty object.  Thanks both for your help in resolving